# Combine Views in asp.net core MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I am new to this, so sorry for my maybe stupid question

I created two tables Movie and Owner. My plan was that it should be possible to add a owner to a movie, so when the view is show up, i get a dropdown that load the content from the owner table

I can Create the standard create, delete etc pages, but if i wish to combine the create page with this new field i am lost

The view

```
  @model MvcMovie.Models.Movie

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Movie</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ReleaseDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ReleaseDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ReleaseDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Genre" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Genre" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Genre" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Price" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Price" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Owners" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Owners" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Owners" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

The models

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace MvcMovie.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Title { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Release Dates")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public string? Genre { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")] 
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        
        

        public virtual ICollection<Owner> Owners { get; set; }

    }
    
        
    
    
    
}
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;



namespace MvcMovie.Models
{
    public class Owner
    {
        

            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string Adress { get; set; }

            
        }
}
```

Controller:

```
namespace MvcMovie.Controllers
{
    public class MoviesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly MvcMovieContext _context;

        public MoviesController(MvcMovieContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Movies
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
              return View(await _context.Movie.ToListAsync());
        }

       

        // GET: Movies/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Movie == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var movie = await _context.Movie
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (movie == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(movie);
        }

        // GET: Movies/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Movies/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Title,ReleaseDate,Genre,Price")] Movie movie)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(movie);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(movie);
        }

        // GET: Movies/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Movie == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var movie = await _context.Movie.FindAsync(id);
            if (movie == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(movie);
        }

        // POST: Movies/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Title,ReleaseDate,Genre,Price")] Movie movie)
        {
            if (id != movie.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(movie);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!MovieExists(movie.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(movie);
        }

        // GET: Movies/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Movie == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var movie = await _context.Movie
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (movie == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(movie);
        }

        // POST: Movies/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            if (_context.Movie == null)
            {
                return Problem("Entity set 'MvcMovieContext.Movie'  is null.");
            }
            var movie = await _context.Movie.FindAsync(id);
            if (movie != null)
            {
                _context.Movie.Remove(movie);
            }
            
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool MovieExists(int id)
        {
          return _context.Movie.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Klaus B, any update?

Answer (score 0):

> My plan was that it should be possible to add a owner to a movie

If so, your model design should be one-to-one instead of one-to-many relationship. Your current model design will be possible to add multiple owners to a movie.

Then, if you use **.NET 6**, it is better for you to remove `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` in your project file, otherwise it will make required validation although you do not add the `[Required]` attribute.

Here is a whole working demo:

Model

```
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Title { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Release Dates")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string? Genre { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public Owner Owner { get; set; }

    //public virtual ICollection<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
}
public class Owner
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Adress { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model Movie

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Movie</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ReleaseDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ReleaseDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ReleaseDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Genre" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Genre" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Genre" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Price" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Price" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Owner.Id" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Owner.Id" asp-items="@ViewBag.Owners" class="form-control" >
                    <option>Select the Owner</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Owner.Id" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Controller

```
// GET: Movies/Create
public IActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Owners = new SelectList(_context.Owner.ToList(), "Id", "Name");
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create (Movie movie)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var owner = _context.Owner.Find(movie.Owner.Id);
        movie.Owner = owner;
        _context.Add(movie);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    ViewBag.Owners = new SelectList(_context.Owner.ToList(), "Id", "Name");
    return View(movie);
}
```